# Proving inequality with non-integer powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given $1 > \tau_1 > \tau_2$ > 0 and $\varepsilon > 0$, how do I prove this inequality?

$$\dfrac{(\varepsilon+1)(\tau_{1}-\tau_{2})}{(1-\tau_{2})^{\varepsilon+1}-(1-\tau_{1})^{\varepsilon+1}}<(1-\tau_{2})^{-\varepsilon}$$

I've tried various rearrangements and derivatives. I've verified numerically that it holds, I just need to show it formally. It's for a research paper in economics where the $\tau$'s are tax rates and $\varepsilon$ is an elasticity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define
$$f(t):=(1-t)^{\varepsilon+1}.$$
By the mean value theorem,
$$\frac{f(\tau_1)-f(\tau_2)}{\tau_1-\tau_2}=f'(\tau)$$
for some $\tau\in(\tau_2,\tau_1)\subset(\tau_2,1)$
and therefore,
$$\frac{(\varepsilon+1)(\tau_1-\tau_2)}{f(\tau_2)-f(\tau_1)}=(1-\tau)^{-\varepsilon}<(1-\tau_2)^{-\varepsilon}.$$

Comment: Many thanks for this, very helpful and elegant!